# Microtype and Soul creates a thin white line after words

Tags: microtype, soul

When using `microtype` and `soul`, if I highlight a text that continues on the next line, I get thin white lines after the words on the first line. Here is some code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}

\begin{document}
\sethlcolor{red!50}
\hl{This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.}

\hl{This is an example.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see from the image, this does not happen when the text doesn't continue to the next line.
Any ideas?

Comment: Does the problem persist without microtype? EDIT: I see the problem goes away without microtype.

Comment: But the example shown *does* have the gap between the lines in the "continued" text.

Comment: Problem goes away when you turn off expansion, like so: `\usepackage[expansion=false]{microtype}`

Comment: or use lualatex + lua-ul instead.

Comment: you could set some more overlap, e.g.: `\setuloverlap{0.5pt}` (default is 0.25pt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I see it, you have two options. Either turn off expansion in `microtype`

```
\usepackage[expansion=false]{microtype}
```

or use `LuaLaTeX` together with `lua-ul` instead:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor,lua-ul}

\LuaULSetHighLightColor{red!50}

\begin{document}

\highLight{This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.}

\highLight{This is an example.}
\end{document}
```